# Django model/form clean, validate, and unique

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a Model and ModelForm with "name" and "client" fields that have the following cleaning and validation characteristics. I can manage each individual requirement but can't seem get them to work together.

- An authenticated user can enter a name for an Item
- Item is saved with the name and forced to the client that is associated with the user account.
- Name is cleaned via ' '.join(name.strip().split())
- Name is validated so that (cleaned_name.lower(),client) is unique

  - EG: If "FOO BAR" exists in the user's associated client, user would get an error if they enter "foo bar"

It is a fairly simple model:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("client", "name"),)

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,related_name='items',null=True,blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)

    def clean_name(self):
        return  ' '.join(self.cleaned_data['name'].strip().split())
```

All item creates/updates are done via Django REST Framework:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id','name')

    def create(self,validated_data):
        item = Item.objects.create(name=validated_data['name'],client=self.context['request'].user.client)
        item.save()
        return item
```

I would prefer as much of the logic in the Model as possible (eg, not use SQL to create indexes), but could push some of the validation to the serializer if need be.

Tx.

Comment: Would it be acceptable for your `clean_name` to convert it to lowercase? e.g. `return ' '.join(self.cleaned_data['name'].lower()strip().split())`. Then the unique together constraint will handle your validation for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work since I need to keep the capitalization as entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following. The only caveat is that I have to include a name_slug field to store for sorting purposes.

models.py

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'item'
        ordering = ['name_slug']

    # relations
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,related_name='items',null=True,blank=False)

    # attributes
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
    name_slug = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        self.name = ' '.join(self.name.strip().split())
        if Item.objects.filter(client=self.client,name__iexact=self.name).count() > 0:
            raise ValidationError({'name': 'Name already exists. Please enter a different name'})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name_slug = '-'.join(self.name.split()).lower()
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id','name','name_slug')
        read_only_fields = ('name_slug',)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs['client'] = self.context['request'].user.client
        instance = Item(**attrs)
        instance.clean()
        return { k: getattr(instance,k) for k in attrs.keys()}
```